# jQuery remove not working TypeError

Tags: jquery, typeerror

I dynamically added a form with id `#form1` to the page. The form contains several inputs. Form has resizable draggable ad formwizard attached to it. When i destroy all 3 (resizable draggable and formwizard) then try to remove the form by doing `$('#form1').remove()`, i get the following error even thought i can see the form on screen and in DOM. What is this error and why is `remove()` not working.

```
TypeError { message="this.element is undefined", source="with(_FirebugCommandLine){$('#form1').remove();\n};", more...}
```

Comment: What's the html mark-up of the page? If you could post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), that'd be helpful, so's we can see what's going on.

Comment: @david, It's a huge code, hard to post on jsfiddle, but hussein's solution did the trick. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to empty before removing.

```
$('#form1').empty().remove();
```

Comment: @pinkie, If I'm not mistaken, It's something to do with the formwizard plugin. I've read something about this before. Try your code without and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: You're right. it's the formwizard plugin. Thanks allot for the solution.